# Find permutations, that totally change the set of cumulative sums

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation, computer-science, cumulative-sum

I've got the following problem:

> Let N be a set of natural numbers with length n.
>
> Let S be the set of all cumulative sums, where a cumulative sum is the sum of the first k elements of a set.
>
> Now, given N, permutate its elements,  so that S_i contains no element of S (i refers to the ith permutation).
>
> Find as many of these permutations, as possible.

Could anyone help me with an idea? You don't have to give an algorithm, just an approach.

Comment: Does brute force counts as an idea? Especially given "_Find as many of these permutations, as possible_" clause this might be the choice.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the last element in `S_i` (or `S`) is the sum of all elements. Regardless of how you permute the elements, this element will always be in the list (btw, calling `N` or `S` a set is syntactically wrong if you refer to an order).

Therefore, there is no permutation of `N` having `S_i` disjoint from `S`.